# What's the difference using extension type (cdef) and set up pure python code?

Tags: cython

Note that I'm new to the C language. According to [Basic Tutorial of Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html), I believe there are two ways of using Cython: Building the extension of pure Python code, and using Ctype variable (cdef).

What I don't understand is the difference between them. Which one of them is the more efficient or proper way to using Cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly historical.

- Originally Cython only supported `cdef` declarations.
- Pure Python mode was added as a way of adding declarations to a file to help speed it up while not *requiring* Cython.
- Python added type annotations. Cython can increasingly use these (with the `annotation_typing` directive, which defaults to true). If you like the syntax of these better than `cdef` then use them. Or not.

The `cdef` version is slightly better tested and there's still gaps in what you can do in "pure Python" mode. Especially with respect to interfacing with native C/C++. But mostly they are different ways to achieve the same thing and they should generate largely the same code, so you should use whichever you prefer. You can also use a mixture.

Answer (score 1):

Most Python codes can be directly "cythonized", with no change to your code. Nevertheless, to get the best of Cython, you need to adapt your Python code by providing the `cdef` and the type of your variables. Not mandatory, but essential to get the decent speed up that you expect from Cython.